# How to see XFA forms in i-Pad?

Tags: ipad, livecycle

I would like to develop an interactive XFA form in LiveCycle Designer ES -2 which will support Windows as well as i-Pad. But the problem is when I open an XFA form it does not show the form rather it shows the form can not be shown(If the form has scripts within it).It only shows simple PDF documents in read only format.It also does not show the button in Acroforms.There is no interactivity related with the form.I would like to know is there any way to show the interactive PDf forms?

Answer (score 2):

There is also another solution from SPZAP designed for Microsoft SharePoint and supporting XFA forms in PDFs and in some way in HTML5 compliant browsers. It has a form designer that runs in a browser (html5) and two kinds of runtime that are SharePoint integrated and are displaying PDF either in Adobe Acrobat Reader (probably Foxit in future) or converted as html5 structure (with some limitations in latter case). http://www.pdfsharepoint.com

Answer (score 1):

LiveCycle Mobile ES4.0 will be able to render your forms. The look will be similar to HTML rendering. 
http://www.adobe.com/products/livecycle/mobile/

Answer (score 0):

The built-in pdf reader doesn't support dynamic PDF forms, Adobe doesn't have an iOS client and iPad doesn't support flash (natively).

Your only option is to render the form as HTML using LiveCycle Forms ES (server module).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot render an interactive form in iPad as pdf. Reason being Apple doesn't allow any application (except web browser) to run any kind of scripts inside it (In this case Acrobat application, trying to run Javascript).

But you can render it as HTML which can be rendered in a browser and has some strip out functionality than the pdf version but its worth to try.